# new Websocket() return wrong object in Firefox Quantum

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, firefox-quantum

I'm using Firefox Quantum (64.0) and the JS command `new WebSocket()` returns a different object from the specification:

[MDN Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

[HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#the-websocket-interface)

The missing property that is affecting my appllication is the `.close()` function, but there is another differences.

You can see in the image bellow that the returned object has a `.websocket` porperty that contains all the missing ones.
[websocket object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2mAV.png)

Am I doing something wrong? With older versions of Firefox (before Quantum, like 43) or with chrome it works fine.

If it is a problem with firefox, how can I report it?

EDIT:

Adding some code example:

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
exampleSocket.close() // Throw "exampleSocket.close is not a function" in Firefox Quantum, works on chrome
exampleSocket.websocket.close() // Works on Firefox, Throw on chrome.
```

This `exampleSocket.websocket` is not in the documentation.

Edit2:
I tested in other machines that have the firefox versions 60, 61, 63 and 64 and the problem only happened in my machine.
When I removed all plugins from firefox it started to work again.

Comment: But there *is* a `.close()` method; it's right there on the prototype object. Your question would be easier to understand if there were some code to look at.

Comment: @Pointy I added a example. To access the `.close()` I need to use this websocket property that should not exist.

Comment: Hmm well Firefox 63.0.3 certainly doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy the problem was some plugin in my Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the [websocketsniff plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/websocketsniff/) that I had installed.

It even state that the WebSocket object will change:

> Inspect websocket frames in Firefox. How to use: 1) Open Developer
>   Tools 2) Open "Websocket Sniffer" tab
>
> This extension replace native websocket object for custom object. It
>   is dirty hack, but it is single decision